# How to perform the sum-group by function in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

[image]
Here is a table record every staff sales record in every months.

Every responsible staff in every district could be changed .E.g. District A: May :179 ->June: 220

Now , i want to sum all staff sales records from May-2016 to Jul-2016 .
The range should be `D3:I21`.The range can be hard code.

Then paste the result on `L3:M21` .

The sample output should be

> 179 1
>
> 186 7
>
> 222 4
>
> S24 5
>
> ......

How to perform the SQL like `select staffid ,sum(total) from table group by staffid` in VBA ?

## Remark :

Any idea is okay (no need code) .thank you so much

Is it able to do it in VBA? Or putting all data into two column in a virtual space .Then do the calculation later?

I must use VBA because :

This picture is just a example .Behind the real excel is a user form . The admin can select the fromdate and todate .Then ,generate the report according to the selected range .

Delete the row 23-Total is okay . Small modifciation of table structure can be considered .

Comment: Use ADODB, but you are going to have to change your table to have unique fieldnames first (i.e. you can't have two fields called "Total").

Comment: @YowE3K But is it able to do it in VBA? Or putting all data into two column in a virtual space .Then do the calculation?

Comment: Yes, you can use ADODB in VBA.

Comment: @YowE3K Or is it able to do it in VBA without SQL ? because my company is not allowed to use external libraries .

Comment: If you really want to perform SQL without an external library (such as Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects), I don't think you can.  Why do you need SQL?  Why don't you just loop through each staff member and sum each of the values where the staff number matches?  That would be quite easy to do, but the requirement to use SQL to do it just complicates matters.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Use [Pivot Table](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html) by putting all the data into two columns: column staff and column sales.

**Alternatively**, copy ID staff in `Range("D3:D21")` to `Range("L3:L21")` and then put this formula in cell M3:

```
     =E3+INDEX(F$3:G$21,MATCH(L3,F$3:F$21,0),2)+INDEX(H$3:I$21,MATCH(L3,H$3:H21,0),2)
```

then drag cell M3 down to cell M21.

Anyway, you contradict yourself by saying, "*Any idea is okay (no need code)*" and then said "*I must use VBA because*". Which one do you want??

---

### Edit:

The OP said the formula doesn't work properly, but it does work fine. Have a look [this Excel file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7x4BoOdwK8TYXh3T2QxcWQ3UEk). Here is the VBA code that is implementing formula above:

```
Sub evabb()
Dim i As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 3 To 21
            .Cells(i, "L") = .Cells(i, "D")
            .Cells(i, "M").Formula = "=E" & i & "+INDEX(F$3:G$21,MATCH(L" & i & ",F$3:F$21,0),2)+INDEX(H$3:I$21,MATCH(L" & i & ",H$3:H21,0),2)"
        Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i cant .Here is just a sample picture .Behind is a user form . The admin can select the fromdate to todate .Then ,generate the report

Comment: i mean any brief idea is okay . I must use VBA instead of Pivot Table  . Anyway , thanks for your ans .I will try and test this later

Comment: @evabb Well, you can transform my alternative answer to VBA code. It should be easy by using `.Formula` object. That's an idea.

Comment: not working for M4:M21 .The first item 179 is okay .it shows the result of 179-1

Comment: @evabb It works fine. I have tested the formula many times. Have a look my edited answer and download the Excel file that I created for you.